# vim substitution, searching up to a sequence of characters

Tags: regex, vim

I'd like to be able to search a string in `vim` and substitute the part of the string that comes before a multi-character delimiter.  In this case, my delimiter is ",_".  How do I tell `vim` to search up to, but not including, that string?

Comment: How about adding `,_` to the end of the new string instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\ze` to set the end the match. For example:

```
:%s/pattern\ze,_/replacement/gc
```

this matches `pattern` only when followed by `,_`